# How to handle Sagemaker Batch Transform discarding a file with a failed model request

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a large number of JSON requests for a model split across multiple files in an S3 bucket. I would like to use Sagemaker's Batch Transform feature to process all of these requests (I have done a couple of test runs using small amounts of data and the transform job succeeds). My main issue is here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html#batch-transform-errors), specifically:

> If a batch transform job fails to process an input file because of a problem with the dataset, SageMaker marks the job as failed. If an input file contains a bad record, the transform job doesn't create an output file for that input file because doing so prevents it from maintaining the same order in the transformed data as in the input file. When your dataset has multiple input files, a transform job continues to process input files even if it fails to process one. The processed files still generate useable results.

This is not preferable mainly because if 1 request fails (whether its a transient error, a malformmated request, or something wrong with the model container) in a file with a large number of requests, all of those requests will get discarded (even if all of them succeeded and the last one failed). I would ideally prefer Sagemaker to just write the output of the failed response to the file and keep going, rather than discarding the entire file.

My question is, are there any suggestions to mitigating this issue? I was thinking about storing 1 request per file in S3, but this seems somewhat ridiculous? Even if I did this, is there a good way of seeing which requests specifically failed after the transform job finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea: the fewer datapoints are in each file, the less likely a given file is to fail. The issue is that while you can pass a prefix with many files to [CreateTransformJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html#SageMaker-CreateTransformJob-request-MaxPayloadInMB), partitioning one datapoint per file at least requires an S3 read per datapoint, plus a model invocation per datapoint, which is probably not great. Be aware also that [apparently there are hidden rate limits](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=1000415&tstart=0).

Here are a couple options:

1. Partition into small-ish files, and plan on failures being rare. Hopefully, not many of your datapoints would actually fail. If you partition your dataset into e.g. 100 files, then a single failure only requires reprocessing 1% of your data. Note that Sagemaker has built-in retries, too, so most of the time failures should be caused by your data/logic, not randomness on Sagemaker's side.
2. Deal with failures directly in your model. The same doc you quoted in your question also says:

> If you are using your own algorithms, you can use placeholder text, such as ERROR, when the algorithm finds a bad record in an input file. For example, if the last record in a dataset is bad, the algorithm places the placeholder text for that record in the output file.

Note that the reason Batch Transform does this whole-file failure is to maintain a 1-1 mapping between rows in the input and the output. If you can substitute the output for failed datapoints with an error message from inside your model, without actually causing the model itself to fail processing, Batch Transform will be happy.

Comment: I thought CreateTransformJob would still only be called once, and it would take an S3 directory as input with millions of files (each file only containing one model request). Also, my models are only capable of processing one request at a time (cannot take multiple requests in one payload)

Comment: @Sahil On your first point, [you're right](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_TransformS3DataSource.html). With millions of files, you'll also need to watch out for [S3 rate limits](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-request-limit-avoid-throttling/)